# FTPClient with append functionality

Tags: java, ftp

i want to upload files to FTP server from Android application . i am using ftp4j.jar for this as it has the append function to append to file which is already on server . It was working fine before but now it has stopped working appending file .Rest is working . I don't know what is the issue . I did't find any other substitute for ftp4j .

Comment: Have you changed your server? If you have does your new server support append?

Comment: yes,i have changed my server and it supports append, as i have testing it with isResumeSupported() method and it is returning true.

Comment: The Apache commons net library also supports FTP with append mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Apache Commons Net FTPClient appendFile() methods as scai mentioned in the comments. I'm not sure how it works in Android.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#appendFile(java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream)