# Android FTP library with append functionality

Tags: android, ftp, ftp-client, ftplib

I am in search of a java FTP library that works on the android which can append already created file from FTP server without download & upload the same file.

Does anyone know of such a library.

I heard about ftp4j but it is troubling while appending file as mention [here in SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8269407/582571)

Answer (score 2):

[Apache FTP client](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#appendFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream%29) works on Android I believe, and provides the append function you require: